# UPDATE COM CASE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tem alguma forma de eu usar mais de uma coluna de uma mesma tabela em uma instrução case em um update? por exemplo, eu tenho essa tabela com essas 3 linhas

```
create table produto2(
codigo int primary key,
categoria varchar(30),
valor number(7,2));

insert into produto2 values (1001,'A',7.55);
insert into produto2 values (1002,'B',5.95);
insert into produto2 values (1003,'C',3.45);
```

e estou tentado usar um case com a coluna categoria e valor para aumentar o valor em 5,10 e 15 por cento quando a categoria é A,B,C

```
 update produto2 set valor = case when categoria = 'A' then valor*(valor*5/100)
                             case when categoria = 'B' then valor*(valor*10/100)
                             case when categoria = 'B' then valor*(valor*15/100)
                             end;
```

mas não estou tendo sucesso, apenas com um PL/SQL que eu criei, mas como podem ver ele é muito mais trabalhoso, queria tentar simplificar apenas com o case.

```
declare
cursor c_prod is select * from produto;
v_prod c_prod%rowtype;
begin
open c_prod;
loop
fetch c_prod into v_prod;
exit when c_prod%notfound;
end loop;
close c_prod;
if v_prod.categoria = 'A' then
update produto set valor = valor+(valor*5/100) where categoria = 'A';
elsif v_prod.categoria = 'B' then
update produto set valor = valor+(valor*10/100) where categoria = 'B';
elsif v_prod.categoria = 'C' then
update produto set valor = valor+(valor*15/100) where categoria = 'C';
end if;
end;
```

mas enfim, tem alguma forma?

Comment: update produto2 set valor = (case when categoria = 'A' then valor*(valor*5/100)
                                  when categoria = 'B' then valor*(valor*10/100)
                                  when categoria = 'B' then valor*(valor*15/100)
                                  else valor end);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tem um erro de sintaxe no seu Update, deve-se utilizar apenas um case e cada condição dentro de um bloco when

```
update produto2
   set valor = case
                 when categoria = 'A' then
                  valor * (valor * 5 / 100)
                 when categoria = 'B' then
                  valor * (valor * 10 / 100)
                 when categoria = 'C' then
                  valor * (valor * 15 / 100)
               end;
```